# scala dsl: arguments seem to be position dependent

Tags: scala

I attempted to deal with the question posted at the end of [this article.](https://dzone.com/articles/rolling-your-own-dsl-in-scala) . To be exact, I want to write a dsl that allows something like this `val qux = value of method "someInternalMethod" of bar`. I cannot get a solution which doesn't include any parenthesis. It seems the pattern has to be something like `<object> <method> <argument> <method> <argument> <method> <argument>` and this pattern doesn't apply to the above question since "someInternalMethod" happens to be on the method position hence it cannot be arbitrary. Could anyone help ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: You could ask the author of blog.

Comment: You can do `the value of method ...`, which would be pretty close ;)

Comment: Where would you put method arguments anyway?